# Split string to get number and split split string into separate columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have I have a column `address` with the string like this:

`Tow 10 Floor 223, Ward AA BB, District CC DD, City E F`

and

`Tow 110 Floor 23, Ward BB AA, District DD CC, City F E`

`...`

(more than 10000 lines)

I want to split this string into separate columns, remove the characters after the 2nd comma and insert column with split value into my table.

Look like this:

---

| Tow | Floor | Ward |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 223 | AA BB |
| 110 | 23 | BB AA |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split_part()`, which doesn't support regex so you'll have to nuke the commas:

```sql
select
     split_part(replace(address, ', ', ''), ' ', 2) as tow,
     split_part(replace(address, ', ', ''), ' ', 4) as floor,
     split_part(replace(address, ', ', ''), ' ', 6) || ' ' || split_part(replace(address, ', ', ''), ' ', 7) as ward
from mytable
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it almost worked, because I forgot that there is a space between `A` and `B` in `Ward` (see my edit) so the result was a bit skewed. Reslut is: ` Tow: 10 | Floor: 223A | Ward: A` . Please help me again

Answer (score 1):

Using [`regexp_match`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html):

```
select (regexp_match(address, '(?<=Tow\s)\d+'))[1] tow,
       (regexp_match(address, '(?<=Floor\s)\d+'))[1] floor,
       (regexp_match(address, '(?<=Ward\s)[^,]+'))[1] ward
from tbl
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/a0UcYkm6).

Comment: Thank you a lot. This is a short way I can do it ♥